# Responsive Design: Images in portrait / landscape mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

So I'm making my theme user-friendly for cellphones, but I really want to make a special thing about images. If the images is landscape, I want the width to be smaller than it would if the images were portrait... And I mean it is possible to do this by the "@media-screen max-width/max-height" thing in css... Am I on the right track? Or do I have to throw in a JS there?

Comment: If you isolate the problem, post the code and a live demo people might help, otherwise this question is not useful.

Comment: You can set the max widths of images, yes. Or do you mean serve an optimized image instead of full size one?

Comment: Please have the title of your thread be a summary of the question/problem, not half a sentence (that you don't even pick up on in your post).

Comment: @KaiQing I mean like... If an image in my content div is portrait, I want the width of the image to be smaller than if the image is landscape, you see where I'm going? :P

Comment: Yeah a standard media query would work so long as you actually set the css properties of those images in question. Have you tried this? Pretty much any example found by a basic "css media query" google search would give a decent example

Answer (score 1):

This should be what your looking for.
It uses a percentage width and an auto height to make sure all the photos have the same width but the height adjusts to make sure the image doesn't become distorted. The phone tag in the css is only to simulate a phone screen. Hope it helps :D

http://jsfiddle.net/LdeGJ/

```
img{
width:90%;
height:auto;
}
```